# Pipewire Integration with Yocto 4.0.13 (kirkstone)

Tags: yocto, pipewire

I am working with yocto project on IMX8MM board, i am trying to replace pulseaudio with pipewire as I have seen pipewire is part of  yocto meta-opembedded/meta-multimedia/recipe-multimedia/pipewire.

But im not able to see pipewire configuration and commands in my image.

And i added the below packages in local.conf file
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " libspa-dbus libpipewire pipewire pipewire-pulse wireplumber pipewire-alsa pipewire-modules-meta pipewire-v4l2"

And i getting the below error message,
Apr 28 18:28:37 phyboard-pollux-imx8mp-3 pipewire[483]: [W][00008.835990] pw.context   | [       context.c:  374 pw_context_new()] 0xaaab10aeba40: can't load dbus library: support/libspa-dbus
Apr 28 18:28:37 phyboard-pollux-imx8mp-3 pipewire[483]: [E][00008.836576] pw.module    | [   impl-module.c:  278 pw_context_load_module()] No module "libpipewire-module-rt" was found
Apr 28 18:28:37 phyboard-pollux-imx8mp-3 pipewire[483]: [E][00008.838528] pw.module    | [   impl-module.c:  278 pw_context_load_module()] No module "libpipewire-module-profiler" was found
Apr 28 18:28:37 phyboard-pollux-imx8mp-3 pipewire[483]: [E][00008.838576] pw.conf      | [          conf.c:  560 load_module()] 0xaaab10aeba40: could not load mandatory module "libpipewire-module-profily
Apr 28 18:28:37 phyboard-pollux-imx8mp-3 pipewire[483]: [E][00008.839009] default      | [      pipewire.c:  125 main()] failed to create context: No such file or directory
Apr 28 18:28:37 phyboard-pollux-imx8mp-3 systemd[1]: pipewire.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=254/n/a
Apr 28 18:28:37 phyboard-pollux-imx8mp-3 systemd[1]: pipewire.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 28 18:28:37 phyboard-pollux-imx8mp-3 systemd[1]: pipewire.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Apr 28 18:28:37 phyboard-pollux-imx8mp-3 systemd[1]: Stopped PipeWire Multimedia Service.
Apr 28 18:28:37 phyboard-pollux-imx8mp-3 systemd[1]: pipewire.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 28 18:28:37 phyboard-pollux-imx8mp-3 systemd[1]: pipewire.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 28 18:28:37 phyboard-pollux-imx8mp-3 systemd[1]: Failed to start PipeWire Multimedia Service.

Can some one help me in integrating pipewire to yocto 4.0.13 (kirkstone) version.